# Rendering Model differences in Sitecore 8.2 vs 9.1

Tags: mvc

I am upgrading a solution from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.1.

In Sitecore 8.2, we have a rendering definition item within Sitecore that only has a View file defined. The rendering definition does **not** have a custom model defined.  The view file (simplified for brevity) looks something like this:

```
@model Company.Feature.FeatureName.Models.MoreLink

<span class="more-link">
    @if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
    {
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("Field Name")
    }
    else
    {
        <a href="@Model.Link" class="more-button">
            @Model.Text
        </a>
    }
</span>
```

Now, in Sitecore 8.2 this Rendering works.

In Sitecore 9.1.1, this exact same view and rendering definition item create an unhandled exception:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Company.Feature.FeatureName.Models.MoreLink'.`

I know how to solve this issue, not a big deal. I'm going to create a model definition accordingly and move on. **My question is: Why (how?) was this working before in Sitecore 8.2, and suddenly it breaks within 9.1?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably had some custom code in Sitecore 8.2 to retrieve the model type from the view that is either no longer present, or no longer working in your Sitecore 9.1 instance.

The typical way of being able to use View renderings without having to specify a model in Sitecore itself is to patch a processor into the `mvc.getModel` pipeline to determine the model type from the view. Alternatively, some people use the Glass Mapper ORM which includes this functionality.

Without this, Sitecore cannot resolve the model correctly and you will get the `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel'` exception you mentioned.

For further reading see my [blog post](https://www.mattfletcher.co.uk/2018/12/21/using-view-renderings-with-glass-mapper-and-compiled-views/) on the subject.

Comment: Checking the `mvc.getModel` pipeline, I see glass processors in my 8.2 instance. Those processors are not within my 9.1 instance.  One of them is `GetModelFromView`, which is probably doing the magic.  Thanks for the tip!